# Nginx returning 404 on new installation

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, laravel, linuxmint

On Linux Mint 20.3 I had working setup for my local development of website:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name cbp.local;

    root /home/gacek/html/cbp/public;

    index           index.php;

    location / {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    if (!-d $request_filename) {
            rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

This is a Laravel application located in `/home/gacek/html/cbp` directory, and the `index.php` entrypoint is located in `/public` subfolder.

After fresh installation of Linux Mint 21.1 the same nginx configuration gives me 404 not found:

> 404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

I tried:

- adjusting the ownership of directory:
  `sudo chown -R gacek:www-data /home/gacek/html/cbp`
- widening the permissions: `sudo chmod -R 776 /home/gacek/html/cbp`
- creating a symlink and adjusting nginx config file `sudo ln -s /home/gacek/html/cbp /var/www/`

The last one I tried because following config works perfectly fine:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.local;

    root /var/www/test;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Why this nginx site config is not working? Where is the difference between the two?

**EDIT**

I have changed the configuration using [guide in Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/deployment#nginx):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name cbp.local;
    root /home/gacek/html/cbp/public;
 
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
 
    index index.php;
 
    charset utf-8;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
 
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 
    error_page 404 /index.php;
 
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/gacek/html/cbp/public$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
 
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

After this change the error displayed on the page changed to:

`File not found.`

And now I get following errors in nginx's error log:

[image]

Comment: That configuration does not contain a statement which generates "404 not found". Check the access and error logs for more details. Use `nginx -T` to view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: @RichardSmith - I have edited my question, added some logs from error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you're most of the way there - you've set up a specific directory to host the content and applied appropriate permissions to the directory, although you haven't confirmed what user nginx is running as, and whether that user is a member of the `www-data` group on the host.

I would suggest adding the user that nginx is running as to the `www-data` group and making sure that group has appropriate permissions

I would actually recommend that you don't make the content directory writeable by default as you have done unless you have a specific reason to do so - and if you do have a specific reason to do so, I'd probably create a dedicated subdirectory which is writeable whilst the root is not.

So in summary, probably:

```
usermod -aG nginx www-data
chmod -R 755 /home/gacek/html/cbp
```

You could actually go one step further to harden the directory permissions in only applying the above to directories/subdirectories, and applying `chmod 644` to all files.

**Edit:** having searched online on your behalf [elsewhere](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/40c4d7f1820df1872a71ab07fd26da45a203e37f), this seems like a good candidate for the potential problem: you may have `ProtectHome=true` in the systemd init file for `php-fpm.service`.

1. Set `ProtectHome=false` in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/php-fpm.service`
2. `systemctl daemon-reload`
3. `systemctl restart nginx.service`
4. `systemctl restart php-fpm.service`

Ironically, I did personally note that it was odd that you'd put the code in a home folder initially rather than, e.g. `/var/www/html/` but decided to keep that to myself - turns out it was relevant!

Comment: Thanks @BE77Y, I have already done that - without change. Nginx is running as www-data

Comment: OK - how about the php-fpm socket you configured, `/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock` - is that also owned by www-data?

Comment: yes - www-data:www-data

Comment: This answer appears to be relating to the same issue (reviewing the error screenshot again it looks like an issue passing paths to php-fpm to me): [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/948898/nginx-and-php-fpm-primary-script-unknown-while-reading-response-header-from-u)

Comment: Actually scratch that - I think I've found the issue here - see my edit in the post @Gacek.

Comment: gacek:~ $ systemctl restart php-fpm.service
Failed to restart php-fpm.service: Unit php-fpm.service not found.

Comment: Yeah, it was important to keep it in home folder, but I gave up. Just moved it to /var/www/cbp and it works. Thanks